# How do I run a separate command shell with output piped through using the more command?

Tags: batch-file, command, piping

Below is the batch file I've created, listing 8 possible options for a user to select information to see (the Menu is all cluttered, but the coding is correct).

```
@ECHO OFF

:MENU
echo
echo Press CTRL + C to exit at any time
echo 
echo 1. attrib- Displays all the attributes of all files in the current directory
echo 2. cipher- Displays encryption state of current folder and any files it contains
echo 3. hostname- Displays the host name portion of the full computer name
echo 4. ipconfig- Displays IPv4 and IPv6 addresses, subnet mask, and default gateway
echo 5. netstat- Active TCP connections(a), ethernet statistics(e),port numbers (n)
echo 6. getmac- Returns media access control address and list of network protocols
echo 7. path- Displays current command path
echo 8. tasklist- Displays list of currently running processes on the local computer
echo 
echo 

set /p T=Enter your choice: 

IF %T% == 1 goto attrib
IF %T% == 2 goto cipher
IF %T% == 3 goto hostname
IF %T% == 4 goto ipconfig
IF %T% == 5 goto netstat
IF %T% == 6 goto getmac
IF %T% == 7 goto path
IF %T% == 8 goto tasklist  

:attrib
attrib | more
goto MENU 

:cipher
cipher | more
goto MENU

:hostname
hostname | more
goto MENU

:ipconfig
ipconfig | more
goto MENU

:netstat
netstat -a -e -n | more
goto MENU

:getmac
getmac | more
goto MENU 

:path
path | more
goto MENU

:tasklist
tasklist | more
goto MENU 

:End
```

I was wondering how commands that provide a lot of information can be run in a separate command shell with output piped through a pager (more command essentially), and also having an appropriate title in this new command window.

For instance, the ipconfig option in the menu displays A LOT of information, that I would like to display in a new command window using the | more command.

Answer (score 1):

```
start "ipconfig" cmd /c "(ipconfig.exe /all | more)&pause"
```

Just ensure the pipe is executed inside the spawned cmd instance filtering the output of the `ipconfig`, and not in the current instance piping the output of the `start` command